# Boost: Comparing variants with apply_visitor

Tags: c++, boost, apply-visitor

Could somebody please tell me why I am getting compiler error for the last line of the following code?

*note*: If I remove the following line, my code gets compiled with no error:

```
appliedEqualityVisitor(compareValue);
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "boost/variant/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


template<typename T>
struct CheckOneTypeEquality : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    T const* value;
    bool operator()( T const& other ) const
    {
        return other == *value;
    }
    template<typename U>
    bool operator()( U const& other ) const
    {
        return false;
    }
    CheckOneTypeEquality( T const& value_ ):value(&value_) {}
};

typedef variant<int, string> MyVariant;
typedef apply_visitor_delayed_t<CheckOneTypeEquality<MyVariant>> AppliedEqualityVisitorType;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int testValue = 12;
    CheckOneTypeEquality<MyVariant> equalityVisitor(testValue);

    AppliedEqualityVisitorType appliedEqualityVisitor = apply_visitor(equalityVisitor);

    MyVariant compareValue = 13;
    appliedEqualityVisitor(compareValue); // <<<<< compile error here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Meysam boost::variant provides `operator==` therefor 2 instances of the same variant can be compared using `operator==`, providing that everyone of the bounded types meets the EqualityComparable concept

Comment: @mark You are right. I was a little misguided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from your visitor class. Boost expects a `void operator()(...)`, instead you provide an `operator()` that returns something.

For your pattern to work, you will have to change the visitor, something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct CheckOneTypeEquality : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    T const* value;
    mutable bool check;
    void operator()( T const& other ) const
    {
        check = other == *value;
    }
    template<typename U>
    void operator()( U const& other ) const
    {
      check = false;
    }
    CheckOneTypeEquality( T const& value_ ):value(&value_), check(false) {}
};
```

Then test the result. Btw. am not sure that your constructor there to which you pass an `int` is safe. You are not holding the reference, rather *pointing* to a temporary instance of the variant which is constructed from the int - which may be out of scope.

**EDIT:** I think what you are trying to do is misguided, given that `boost::variant` already implements `operator==` correctly. For example:

```
MyVariant testValue = 12;

MyVariant compareValue = 13;
MyVariant compareValue2 = 12;
MyVariant compareValue3 = "12";

std::cout << (compareValue == testValue) << std::endl;
std::cout << (compareValue2 == testValue) << std::endl;
std::cout << (compareValue3 == testValue) << std::endl;
```

Works fine - and I think it is what you are trying to accomplish? You want to test that two variants are equally comparable(?) This will work as long as all the objects in your variant are equally comparable.

Comment: You are right. I could also get rid of the error by only changing `boost::static_visitor<>` to `boost::static_visitor<bool>`. This way I cal still have bool return values. It's ["Binary visitation"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html)

Comment: But when I call `appliedEqualityVisitor(compareValue)` it always returns false, no matter what the `compareValue` is. Any idea?

Comment: Thank you for the update. This question was indeed part of a larger question which I have described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13234635/69537). Please take a look at it.  Although the question got closed, I really appreciate if you could give me your idea about it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

About:

> But when I call appliedEqualityVisitor(compareValue) it always returns
>   false, no matter what the compareValue is. Any idea?

I think that you misunderstood the usage of visitors, the operator () is invoked with the actual variant type not with a variant parameter (int in your example).

EDIT:
in the code

```
int testValue = 12;
CheckOneTypeEquality<MyVariant> equalityVisitor(testValue);
```

the testValue is converted to MyVariant when instantiating the visitor.

an boost example of equality [boost link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.advanced)

```
class are_strict_equals
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:

    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()( const T &, const U & ) const
    {
        return false; // cannot compare different types
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()( const T & lhs, const T & rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }

};

boost::variant< int, std::string > v1( "hello" );

boost::variant< double, std::string > v2( "hello" );
assert( boost::apply_visitor(are_strict_equals(), v1, v2) );

boost::variant< int, const char * > v3( "hello" );
assert( !boost::apply_visitor(are_strict_equals(), v1, v3) );
```

The

Comment: This is different to what the OP is trying to achieve (I believe), the problem seems to be how to compare two instances of the same variant...

Comment: in code sample the v1 and v2 instances are compared, however they must be of the same type (int and long for example will always return false).